# sync couchdb with android

Tags: android, couchdb

We have a couchdb server whose contents are managed by a .NET application.

We have a bunch of android clients that we want to synchronize with that DB on a button click. (it is just a list of folders and items, nothing complex)

What is the best Android library to use. I see there is Ektorp, touchdb etc. Ektorp seems a bit heavy. TouchDb-Android seems promising.

Do you guys have any experience with this? Or should I just use GET / POST calls with the couchdb server?

Answer (score 2):

I've done a lot of research on this since I'm working on the same thing.

We have some CMS content we want to push into CouchDB and then have mobile devices sync with the server (cluster) in the cloud.

We ended up going with BigCouch in the cloud (a fork of CouchDB from Cloudant that is stable) and then for the time being we're using Couchbase Mobile.  Unfortunately there is no support for Couchbase Mobile (it has be discontinued by Couchbase), but it's stable.

One of the differences with Couchbase Mobile is that it uses Erlang on the mobile device to run the local Couch instance.  It's a little slow.

TouchDB is what we both will need, but it's not mature enough on Android yet.  TouchDB is a little funkier in that it uses SQLlite for the backend.  It's faster for sure.  They've release TouchDB 1.0 for iOS, and it's good, but they haven't updated the Android port yet.  We found the Android port of TouchDB (also from Couchbase) to not be as stable.  Also if you look at the TouchDB Android code on GitHub, it's a little sloppy.

So we're going with BigCouch in the cloud (instead of regular CouchDB) for clustering support and then Couchbase Mobile on the mobile devices.  Once TouchDB gets more mature for Android, we'll switch to that.  Good news is that they both use Ektorp, so swapping between the two is not hard.  The replication works great.  It's solid and fairly fast.

Just a quick note:  Be careful with Couch replication with mobile devices.  Any documents that are written to a local mobile device *will* replicate back to the server!

**EDIT**

Documents won't always be copied from the local device to the server.  It's an option, but will not *always* be the case.  I spoke too soon.  =/

Comment: "Any documents that are written to a local mobile device will replicate back to the server!" Are you saying filtered replication (http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Replication#Filtered_Replication) is not available with the mobile environments you are using?

Comment: Yeah I recant of that statement. I've found with a simple implementation that this was the case, but I believe it can be prevented.  I'll edit to take that part out. I got filtered replication to work in my environment (BigCouch + Couchbase Mobile and BigCouch + TouchDB).

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely start with one of the libraries, and only revert to GET / POST calls if it turns out the library (or actually, none of the libraries) work out for you.